# php recursive search and count of a value in json

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

I have a json feed with 6 objects all which have objects inside of them. I have an ID of something I am trying to search and count in another object.

```
if (isset($_GET['steamusr'])) {
$user = $_GET['steamusr'];
$myinv = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/'.$user.'/inventory/json/295110/1/';
$content2 = file_get_contents($myinv);
$json2 = json_decode($content2, true);
$imgurlbase = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/';

foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
    $item = $i['market_name'];
    $icon = $i['icon_url'];
    $fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
    $grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
    $id = json_decode($grab, true);
    $itemid = $i['classid'];
foreach($json2->rgInventory as $i2){
  if($i2->$itemid == $itemid){
    $ci = 0;
    $count = $ci++ ;
    }
}
```

All the data comes from rgDescriptions first, then rgInventory has the number of objects to count within it. The item ID comes from $itemid which I then need to search rgInventory for and then count the amount of matching id's in there from the set value $itemid.

My biggest issue is rgInventory has unique objects so I am trying to do a recursive/wildcard search of matching classid's.

The json structure can be found here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?url=http://steamcommunity.com/id/fuigus/inventory/json/295110/1/

Comment: The JSON does not seems to be recursive. It's just a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct in essence  but you're not comparing the right things.

```
$json = json_decode($content2);
foreach ($json["rgDescriptions"] as $item) {
    $num = 0;
    foreach ($json["rgInventory"] as $inventory_entry) {
        if ($inventory_entry["classid"] === $item["classid"]) {
            $num += 1;
        }
    }
    // do something with $num
    var_dump($item["classid"] . ": " . $num);
}
```

The line:

```
if($i2->$itemid == $itemid){
```

Is bad, `$i2->$itemid` resolves to `$i2->1107865473` which doesn't exist. I think you intended `$i2->classid`.

Error like this happen because you're using meaningless, abstract variable names. `$i`, `$i2` and `$content2`, these are meaningless. You're also mixing the terms `itemid` and `classid`, it's easy to get confused.

Also, you're mixing bracket notation and object notation. Pick one and stick to it.